# What is the meaning of "ripening in the shade" as a metaphor?

Tags: metaphors, figures-of-speech

In *David Copperfield*, Dickens wrote, "Sometimes a life glides away, and finds it still ripening in the shade." I understand some idea of a ripening life but not "in the shade".

Comment: If the usual way is for it to ripen in the sun, then it’s something of an accomplishment for it to have ripened in the shade. The figure of speech seems to refer to a more difficult path to success, but success nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful!!